# Handling Permutations of If Statements in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, permutation

I have some Lists which store values. Now I want to create If-Statements to handle this but that's to much. For example:

```
 if(list1.Count==0 && list2.Count==0)
 {
 //do something
 } 
 if(list1.Count==0 && list3.Count==0)
 {
 //do something
 }
 if(list1.Count==0 && list2.Count==0 && list3.Count==0)
 {
 //do something
 }
```

so there is a huge amount of if-statements if I have about 10 Lists. Is there a better way to handle that? I haven't found anything useful.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think your question would be better in [CodeReview.SE]. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Hard to answer this without an understanding of the logic you need to implement ...

Comment: How many 'do something's do you have?

Comment: @SonerGönül - this is not about reviewing.

Comment: Posting to CodeReview like @SonerGönül said might help you. If you can't use switch/case, what you could do is add the counts of the lists and save them in ints, then check those values instead. I don't know if this makes sense to you though, since I don't know your specific example.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Actually, it is. The OP is asking for ways to improve his solution, not an error in his code. It's working, he just doesn't like the code. This is definitely Code Review material, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hey! I have about ten. So I would need to check for example 1 and 2,1 and 3,1 and 4,...,1 and 2 and 3 and 4, 1 and 2 and 3 and 5,..., 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and...and 10. So a lot of statements. Is this possible with a loop and an array/list of objects/functions ?

Comment: How can I move this question to Code Review?

Comment: @HenkHolterman You can read [Martijn Pieters's answer on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266344/447156): _CodeReview: Your code works but you'd love to hear how it could work better_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the way that i can give the suggestion seeing the code pasted here is that you have some duplicated stuff like this

```
               if(list1.Count==0 && list2.Count==0)
```

and then

```
              if(list1.Count==0 && list2.Count==0 && list3.Count==0)
```

One of the suggestion will be to per-calculate the condition like this

```
              bool onetwo =  list1.Count==0 && list2.Count==0;
              bool thirdalone = list3.Count == 0;
```

Now the code can be more better like this

```
               if(onetwo){
               }
               if(onetwo && thirdalone){
               }
```

If you wish you can use the Bitmasking to generate all of them for example , here n is total lists we have.

```
             bool[] statu = new bool[1 << n];        

             for(int i = 1 ; i < (1<< n) ; i++){
                  bool result = true;                  
                  for(int j = 0 ; j < 32 ; j++){
                    if(i & ( 1 << j) > 0){
                        //this position is part of set
                         if(list[j].count == 0)
                                  result = false;
                     }
                 }
                 status[i] = result;
             }
```

But it is just more semantic way , nothing can be  performance enhancement etc..

Comment: Ok that's a little bit better that mine but isn't there a way to iterate over that? Just for testing one with each other that are 28 if statements.

Comment: Ok thanks! I don't need a performance enhancement. I just wanted that a little bit shorter for not writing so much code.

Comment: upvoted this because it is better than my attempt : )

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check every permutation you can do something like this:

```
bool b1 = ( list1.count == 0 );
bool b2 = ( list2.count == 0 );
bool b3 = ( list3.count == 0 );
bool b4 = ( list4.count == 0 );
// etc etc

BitArray arr = new BitArray(new bool[4] { b1, b2, b3, b4 });
byte[] bits = new byte[4];
arr.CopyTo(bits, 0);
int x = BitConverter.ToInt32(bits, 0);

switch (x)
{
   case 1: // only list 1 is empty
   case 2: // only list 2 is empty
   case 3: // only list 1 and list 2 are empty
   case x: // and so on.
}
```

I wouldn't say is it's any more readable, but I'd rather maintain something like this is future than a giant if/else/else if block.